# Java - visually drag a swing element

Tags: java, user-interface, drag-and-drop, draggable

Is there a similar solution to http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.DragDropDemo/DragDropDemo.html#PaletteExample but for normal Java applications, i.e. allowing gui elements to be dragged around on a canvas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.  No it's not trivial.

You'll want to become farmiluar with the code D'n'D API [How to drag and drop with Java 2, Part 1](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-1999/jw-03-dragndrop.html)

You may like to have a read through

- [Smooth JList Drop Target Animation](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/04/smooth-jlist-drop-target-animation.html)
- [Smooth Tree Drop Animation](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/05/smooth-tree-drop-animation.html)
- [My Drag Image is Better Than Yours](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/05/my-drag-image-is-better-than-yours.html)
- [Dead Simple Drags](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/06/dead-simple-drags.html)
- [Fancy Drops](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/06/fancy-drops.html)
- [Drag Images for Everyone...and we do mean Everyone](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/07/drag-images-for-everyoneand-we-do-mean.html)
- [Drop Target Navigation, or You Drag Your Bags](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/08/drop-target-navigation-or-you-drag.html)
- [Swing Drag Images, Improved](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/08/swing-drag-images-improved.html)
- [Improved Drag Images](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2007/04/improved-drag-images.html)

You may also want to become familiar with the [`GlassPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)