# Drag and Drop between two panels using swing?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, awt

I am new in Swing. I have requirement to implement drag and drop using swing. In current frame contains different panels i.e.,Center Panel & LeftPanel have sub panels i.e., Controls Panel,Properties Panel.I trying to drag and drop the labels/jbuttons/Images from Control Panel into Center Panel.These panels are used BorderLayout

[image]

I tried drag and drop with Mouse Event.I put mouse listner on Control Panel. When I dropping the label/image into center panel.It reads -X & Y Cooridnates and check the code

```
private void mak_lis(final SLabel l) {
   l.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m) {
       System.out.println("mak_lis Mouse mousePressed");

    setCursor(yd);
    // l.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1,1,1,1,Color.black));

    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m) {
       l.setBorder(null);
       setCursor(dc);
       System.out.println("mak_lis Mouse mouseReleased");
       int x = -(m.getX() + l.getX() - leftPanel.getX());
       int y = m.getY() + l.getY() + leftPanel.getY();
       System.out.println("mak_lis Mouse mouseReleased" + "x" + x+ "y" + y);
       if (y > 0 && x > 0 && y < leftPanel.getHeight() && x < leftPanel.getWidth()) {
        leftPanel.add(new_lab(l, x, y));
                leftPanel.repaint();
        Component[] components1 = leftPanel.getComponents();
        Component component = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < components1.length; i++) {
          // System.out.println("components iii"+ components1[i]);
        component = components1[i];

            }

    }
}

});
}
```

Please tell me is there any missing here. What is best approches to achieve drag and drop functionality?

Comment: *"I am implementing designer tool using swing."*  A D'n'D GUI designer?  (shudder)  There are already too many of them creating problems that GUI programmers have to fix later.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I would say there are too many programmers creating problems with tools that they don't understand ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the priority mouse listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273923/how-can-i-set-the-priority-mouse-listener)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how drag and drop is accomplished in Java/Swing

There are plenty of examples on SO...

- [Drag and Drop custom object from JList into JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855184/drag-and-drop-custom-object-from-jlist-into-jlabel/13856193#13856193)
- [Java - How to drag and drop JPanel with its components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201734/java-how-to-drag-and-drop-jpanel-with-its-components/11443501#11443501)
- [how to drag and drop files from a directory in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597233/how-to-drag-and-drop-files-from-a-directory-in-java/13597635#13597635)
- [Java - visually drag a swing element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387086/java-visually-drag-a-swing-element/13389619#13389619)

I'd also recommend that you checkout [How to drag and drop with Java 2](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-1999/jw-03-dragndrop.html)

Comment: As my requirment,I dont any JCompenent in dropped panel.So how Can i dropped JCompnent into this panel.Please suggest how to approach these scenerio?

Comment: You can't.  You MUST have a active component, attached to a native peer, displayed on the screen in order to have the ability to receive mouse events, that's how Swing/Java works.  How do you expect to be able to "paint" something on the screen if it's not some kind of component?

Comment: +1 also see my [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14276466/1133011) which shows how to drag and drop swing components like JComponents between JPanels etc