# Dragging a JLabel across Multiple JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

My App comprises of a `JFrame` which have a `JPanel` placed at Center and another `JPanel` at South.The center `JPanel` is a grid of further `JPanel`. The south `JPanel` is a horizontal array of `Jpanels`.I have multiple images in South Panel which I want to move to the central Grid. I have gone through DnD tutorials on docs.oracle.com but I couldn't find a way out.

```
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.*;
            import javax.swing.*;

            class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                    TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler();
                    handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
                }
            }

            public class IQ {
                JFrame frame;
                JPanel centerPanel;
                JPanel bottomPanel;
                JPanel cPanel1;
                JPanel cPanel2;
                JPanel cPanel3;
                JPanel cPanel4;
                JPanel cPanel5;
                JPanel cPanel6;
                JPanel cPanel7;
                JPanel cPanel8;
                JPanel cPanel9;

                JLabel clabel1;
                JLabel clabel2;
                JLabel clabel3;
                JLabel clabel4;
                JLabel clabel5;
                JLabel clabel6;
                JLabel clabel7;
                JLabel clabel8;
                JLabel clabel9;

                JPanel bPanel1;
                JPanel bPanel2;
                JPanel bPanel3;
                JPanel bPanel4;
                JPanel bPanel5;
                JPanel bPanel6;
                JPanel bPanel7;
                JPanel bPanel8;
                JPanel bPanel9;

                JLabel blabel1;
                JLabel blabel2;
                JLabel blabel3;
                JLabel blabel4;
                JLabel blabel5;
                JLabel blabel6;
                JLabel blabel7;
                JLabel blabel8;
                JLabel blabel9;
                ImageIcon img;

                public void go() {
                    frame = new JFrame();

                    centerPanel = new JPanel();

                    centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
                    cPanel1 = new JPanel();
                    clabel1 = new JLabel();
                    cPanel1.add(clabel1);
                    cPanel1.setBackground(Color.red);
                    cPanel2 = new JPanel();
                    clabel2 = new JLabel();
                    cPanel2.add(clabel2);
                    cPanel2.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                    cPanel3 = new JPanel();
                    clabel3 = new JLabel();
                    cPanel3.add(clabel3);
                    cPanel3.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                    cPanel4 = new JPanel();
                    clabel4 = new JLabel();
                    cPanel4.add(clabel4);
                    cPanel4.setBackground(Color.blue);
                    cPanel5 = new JPanel();
                    clabel5 = new JLabel();
                    cPanel5.add(clabel5);
                    cPanel5.setBackground(Color.magenta);
                    cPanel6 = new JPanel();
                    clabel6 = new JLabel();
                    cPanel6.add(clabel6);
                    cPanel6.setBackground(Color.orange);
                    cPanel7 = new JPanel();
                    clabel7 = new JLabel();
                    cPanel7.add(clabel7);
                    cPanel7.setBackground(Color.gray);
                    cPanel8 = new JPanel();
                    clabel8 = new JLabel();
                    cPanel8.add(clabel8);
                    cPanel8.setBackground(Color.black);
                    cPanel9 = new JPanel();
                    clabel9 = new JLabel();
                    cPanel9.add(clabel9);
                    cPanel9.setBackground(Color.green);

                    centerPanel.add(cPanel1);
                    centerPanel.add(cPanel2);
                    centerPanel.add(cPanel3);
                    centerPanel.add(cPanel4);
                    centerPanel.add(cPanel5);
                    centerPanel.add(cPanel6);
                    centerPanel.add(cPanel7);
                    centerPanel.add(cPanel8);
                    centerPanel.add(cPanel9);

                    bottomPanel = new JPanel();

                    bPanel1 = new JPanel();
                    blabel1 = new JLabel();
                    img = new ImageIcon("1.png");
                    blabel1.setIcon(img);
                    bPanel1.add(blabel1);

                    bPanel2 = new JPanel();
                    blabel2 = new JLabel();
                    img = new ImageIcon("2.png");
                    blabel2.setIcon(img);
                    bPanel2.add(blabel2);

                    bPanel3 = new JPanel();
                    blabel3 = new JLabel();
                    img = new ImageIcon("3.png");
                    blabel3.setIcon(img);
                    bPanel3.add(blabel3);

                    bPanel4 = new JPanel();
                    blabel4 = new JLabel();
                    img = new ImageIcon("4.png");
                    blabel4.setIcon(img);
                    bPanel4.add(blabel4);

                    bPanel5 = new JPanel();
                    blabel5 = new JLabel();
                    img = new ImageIcon("5.png");
                    blabel5.setIcon(img);
                    bPanel5.add(blabel5);

                    bPanel6 = new JPanel();
                    blabel6 = new JLabel();
                    img = new ImageIcon("6.png");
                    blabel6.setIcon(img);
                    bPanel6.add(blabel6);

                    bPanel7 = new JPanel();
                    blabel7 = new JLabel();
                    img = new ImageIcon("7.png");
                    blabel7.setIcon(img);
                    bPanel7.add(blabel7);

                    bPanel8 = new JPanel();
                    blabel8 = new JLabel();
                    img = new ImageIcon("8.png");
                    blabel8.setIcon(img);
                    bPanel8.add(blabel8);

                    bPanel9 = new JPanel();
                    blabel9 = new JLabel();
                    img = new ImageIcon("9.png");
                    blabel9.setIcon(img);
                    bPanel9.add(blabel9);

                    bottomPanel.add(bPanel1);
                    bottomPanel.add(bPanel2);
                    bottomPanel.add(bPanel3);
                    bottomPanel.add(bPanel4);
                    bottomPanel.add(bPanel5);
                    bottomPanel.add(bPanel6);
                    bottomPanel.add(bPanel7);
                    bottomPanel.add(bPanel8);
                    bottomPanel.add(bPanel9);

                    MouseListener listener = new DragMouseAdapter();
                    blabel1.addMouseListener(listener);
                    blabel2.addMouseListener(listener);
                    blabel3.addMouseListener(listener);
                    blabel4.addMouseListener(listener);
                    blabel5.addMouseListener(listener);
                    blabel6.addMouseListener(listener);
                    blabel7.addMouseListener(listener);
                    blabel8.addMouseListener(listener);
                    blabel9.addMouseListener(listener);

                    blabel1.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
                    blabel2.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
                    blabel3.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
                    blabel4.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
                    blabel5.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
                    blabel6.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
                    blabel7.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
                    blabel8.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
                    blabel9.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));

                    frame.setSize(800, 600);

                    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, bottomPanel);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, centerPanel);

                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }

                public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
                    IQ s = new IQ();
                    s.go();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201734/java-how-to-drag-and-drop-jpanel-with-its-components/11443501#11443501) or [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478413/move-component-after-drag-and-drop/16481711#16481711)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sir I have examined the examples but havnt got solution relative to my problem.

Comment: Well, sad news, those are two basic mechanisms, either you use the `Transferable` API to transfer the data that is represented by you UI components or you use the core DnD API to do move the phyiscal component

Comment: You may also wish to post what you have tried

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have uploaded the Source Code.This code let us move images within South Panel only.